# around_filter stubbing in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec2

Hi I am trying to stub an around_filter method in controller which return true always,using the below source code in rspec

```
before(:each) do
  controller.stub(:catch_exceptions).and_return(true)
end
after(:each) do
  controller.stub(:catch_exceptions).and_return(true)
end
```

but it fails. When i change that particular method as before_filter then it works fine? can anyone help me plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly stub an `around_filter`, you should `yield` for the rest of the operation to work, otherwise, you are simply stubbing the whole action...

```
controller.stub(:catch_exceptions).and_yield
```